# Matching data between padding

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match some strings in a binary file and the strings appear to be padded. As an example, the word PROGRAM could be in the binary like this:

```
%$##@P^&#!)00000R{]]]////O.......G"""""R;;$#!*%&#*A/////847M
```

In that example, the word `PROGRAM` is there but it is split up and it's between random data, so I'm trying to use regex to find it.

Currently, this is what I came up with but I don't think this is very effectie:

```
(?<=P)(.*?)(?=R)(.*?)(?=O)(.*?)(?=G)(.*?)(?=R)(.*?)(?=A)(.*?)(?=M)
```

Comment: You could do it without regex. If in `s` is your binary string: `s.translate(dict((ord(ch), '') for ch in set('PROGRAM').symmetric_difference(s)))` This will filter out every padding character, leaving only "PROGRAM" (if there's any)

Comment: I would suggest that you'd get far better efficiency by simply writing a loop to check each character in sequence and mark off each expected letter as you find it. Regex is powerful and elegant, but it can be overkill for simple parsing extractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get PROGRAM from the string, one option might be to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a negated character class to remove all that you don't want.

```
[^A-Z]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6HWen/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1r2io1)

For example:

```
import re
test_str = "%$##@P^&#!)00000R{]]]////O.......G\"\"\"\"\"R;;$#!*%&#*A/////847M"
pattern = r'[^A-Z]+'
print(re.sub(pattern, '', test_str))
```

Result

> PROGRAM

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you and is more efficient than your current solution:

```
P[^R]+R[^O]+O[^G]+G[^R]+R[^A]+A[^M]+M
```

Explanation:

`P[^R]+` - match `P`, than one or more characters other than `R`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/scoNBl/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the desired output might be, I'm guessing maybe this expression,

```
(?=.*?P.*?R.*?O.*?G.*?R.*?A.*?M).*?(P).*?(R).*?(O).*?(G).*?(R).*?(A).*?(M)
```

might be a start.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GpEc1P/1/), if you wish to explore further or simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/GpEc1P/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.